# react native webview onNavigationStateChange is not a function (when running jest test)

Tags: javascript, react-native, webview, jestjs

I have a `import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';` from the react-native-community. Which is implemented in my react-native app like this:

```
<WebView
  key={ this.state.uri }
  source={{ uri: this.state.signedIn && this.state.shareUrl || this.state.uri }}
  style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
  onMessage={this.onMessage}
  onNavigationStateChange={this.setWebViewUrlChanged}
  onLoadEnd={syntheticEvent => {
    this.setState({ loading: false });
  }}
  onLoadStart={syntheticEvent => {
    this.setState({ loading: true });
  }}
/>
```

The onNavigationStateChange prop is called when I, from the running application withing the webview call `window.location.realod(url)`

My handler function looks like this:

```
setWebViewUrlChanged = webviewState => {
  if (webviewState.url !== this.state.initialUrl) {
    this.setState({ uri: webviewState.url });
  }
};
```

And is tested on phone and emulator, it works perfectly. I have even console logged state before/after and confirmed that state is updated and the function is called.

However, I am trying to test this with jest unit test.

```
it('should set webview uri', () => {
  console.log(snap.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].props);
  snap.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].props.onNavigationStateChange({ url: 'some-new-url' });
  expect(snap.state().uri).toEqual('some-new-url');
});
```

When running the test I get error:

> TypeError:
>   snap.children[0].children[0].children[0].children[0].props.onNavigationStateChange
>   is not a function

and from the console.log line above I get the webviews props, where this function is missing:

```
  { style:
     [ { flex: 1 },
       { backgroundColor: '#ffffff' },
       { width: '100%', height: '100%' } ],
    source:
     { uri: 'https://test-domain.eu.ngrok.io/static/dashboard/index.html' },
    injectedJavaScript: undefined,
    bounces: undefined,
    scrollEnabled: undefined,
    pagingEnabled: undefined,
    cacheEnabled: true,
    decelerationRate: undefined,
    contentInset: undefined,
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets: undefined,
    hideKeyboardAccessoryView: undefined,
    allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures: undefined,
    incognito: undefined,
    userAgent: undefined,
    onLoadingStart: [Function],
    onLoadingFinish: [Function],
    onLoadingError: [Function],
    onLoadingProgress: [Function],
    onMessage: [Function],
    messagingEnabled: true,
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest: [Function],
    scalesPageToFit: undefined,
    allowsInlineMediaPlayback: undefined,
    mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction: undefined,
    dataDetectorTypes: undefined,
    useSharedProcessPool: true,
    allowsLinkPreview: undefined,
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator: undefined,
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator: undefined,
    directionalLockEnabled: undefined }
```

So in the test rendered webview only the onMessage function is as in my object, but all my onLoadStart/End and the `onNavigationStateChange` are not rendered.

But these functions that are missing works perfectly fine when project is compiled and running on device. How can I fix this, so that I can include unit tests for these functions?

The snap shot used in the test case is generated like so:

```
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

beforeEach(async () => {
  snapshot = renderer.create(<App />);
  snap = snapshot.toJSON();
});
```

Comment: I haven't used jest with react native, but with regular react for web. And we have experienced how we mount to component do have something to say for how we can test different things. So how is this `snap`-variable initiated?

Comment: using the react-test-rendere, I have updated my question with more info

Comment: I would recommend splitting up the tests since it seems like you want to test the WebView, but you mount the whole app. If you have the whole application in one file, it can be very hard to test like this.

Also found this interesting [article](https://medium.com/@pshrmn/testing-react-native-components-in-node-with-react-test-renderer-cb2985402dce)

Comment: Thanks for your assistence! Eventually I switched test renderer, and that helped a whole lot. My components are now rendere 1:1 in the snapshots with enzyme. Added an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by switching test renderer. I installed `enzyme`, `enzyme-to-json`, `enzyme-adapter-react-16`

**Test modified:**

```
describe('with setting', () => {
  let snapshot;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    // some mocking of asyncStorage
  });

  it('should match snapshot', async () => {
    snapshot = shallow(<App />)
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 100)); // to allow async componentDidMount to finish.
    expect(snapshot).toMatchSnapshot()
  });

  it('should set webview uri', () => {
    snapshot.find('WebView').props().onNavigationStateChange({ url: 'some-new-url' });
    expect(snapshot.state().uri).toEqual('some-new-url');
  });
});
```

The `shallow` function comes from configuring enzyme for jest in setup.js

```
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

// React 16 Enzyme adapter
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

// Make Enzyme functions available in all test files without importing
global.shallow = shallow;
global.render = render;
global.mount = mount;
```

The setup.js is pointet to in the jest configuration (in my case in package.json)

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "<rootDir>/react-native/jest/setup.js"
    ]
  }
```

Hope this will help others who have issues with misalignment of compiled rendered components and mocked (test) rendered component.